# How to secure a remote MySQL database connection against Jar decompilation?

Tags: java, mysql, security

I have a database-backed GUI that will be used by clients who are not on the same network as the database where queries will be executed.

How can I build this structure for this client-to-base communication process in order to secure my credentials?

My concern is that, since the jar can be decompiled, I won't be able to secure the code from the clients.

I have a couple of ideas, but they won't work:

1. If I make a file that will contain the username and the password and I read them via the program so that they won't be visible in the code, the client could still read the same code, see the path of the file, and open it, revealing the credentials.
2. If I encrypt the contents of the file and do the same process, the client will still see the decryption method, and can use that to create a temporary application and get the decrypted credentials.
3. I could use a web server to send requests and the server connects to the database and returns the data to me in the application. But by seeing the way of communication with the web server, the client can actually take this code, create a temporary application, execute the code, and get the same result as the above two scenarios.

Comment: I suggest you use API based approach instead of making database connection directly from jar package.

Comment: @glovemobile thank you for your response. Even with an api approach, the client can see how the program will communicate with the api and that means he can do it alone and get/send data. Am i wrong?

Comment: Put credentials in API for security and monitor it with activity log if you want to be sure.

Comment: @glovemobile I'm sorry, I can't understand the whole idea. In order to put credentials in an api, I have to send them also via code in order to authenticate. Once again, we have the same problem. The code is there and anyone can see how java can send requests to an entity.

Comment: The users of your application must be registered to your system. They will have username and password. Use username and password as API credential. This is just simple example. You can make it more complex secure if you have to.

Comment: @glovemobile I can see your point and thank you for answering to my questions. But this seems to be like a game where I'm returning to the starting point over and over. I can reply to your post by saying "What stops the client to take the code after the X button, paste it to another project and run it 50 times with the api calls and all the necessary pieces". I mean, no matters what authentication ill put on it. Since the code is visible, it means that every project can have the same way of authentication as the main one. Maybe I cant understand how it will work, I don't know.

Comment: After reading your comments, I am assuming you are protecting your code also, not only protecting your data. You can use Code Obfuscation for java, mostly paid service. Am I wrong?

Comment: @glovemobile You are right! Just because by protecting my code, it will protect my data too. I also thought about obfuscation but everywhere (when they suggest it) I can see that even this 'way' can show you the original code (it requires a lot of knowledge but its not impossible).

Comment: Take a look https://java-source.net/open-source/obfuscators